# Can't read XML with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm receiving through cUrl an XML generated with PHP with this code:

```
$c = curl_init("http://www.domain.com/script.php");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $xmlstr = curl_exec($c);
```

If I echo the $xmlstr variable it shows the following:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
        <XGetPasoParadaREGResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <XGetPasoParadaREGResult>
        <PasoParada><cabecera>false</cabecera>
        <e1>
        <minutos>1</minutos>
        <metros>272</metros>
        <tipo>NORMAL</tipo>
        </e1>
        <e2>
        <minutos>7</minutos>
        <metros>1504</metros>
        <tipo>NORMAL</tipo>
        </e2><linea>28
        </linea>
        <parada>376</parada>
        <ruta>PARQUE ALCOSA</ruta>
        </PasoParada>
        </XGetPasoParadaREGResult><status>1</status></XGetPasoParadaREGResponse>
        </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Which is correct and the same generated at the script. However, if I try to do the following

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
    if (!is_object($xml))
        throw new Exception('Reading XML error',1001);
    echo $xml->e1->minutos;
```

Doesn't show anything and print_r the object prints an empty object. What could be wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($xml)`?

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { } but the string is fine and if saved as XML is well interpreted in every browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two main problems, firstly you aren't taking into account any namespaces (e.g. `soap`) and secondly you aren't traversing the XML hierarchy to get at the desired element.

The "simple" way would be:

```
$minutos = (int) $xml
                     ->children('soap', TRUE)     // <soap:*>
                     ->Body                       // <soap:Body>
                     ->children('')               //   <*> (default/no namespace prefix)
                     ->XGetPasoParadaREGResponse  //   <XGetPasoParadaREGResponse>
                     ->XGetPasoParadaREGResult    //     <XGetPasoParadaREGResult>
                     ->PasoParada                 //       <PasoParada>
                     ->e1                         //         <e1>
                     ->minutos;                   //           <minutos> yay!
```

You could also make an XPath query for the value:

```
// Our target node belongs in this namespace
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('n', 'http://tempuri.org/');
// Fetch <minutos> elements children to <e1>
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//n:e1/n:minutos');
// $nodes will always be an array, get the first item
$minutos = (int) $nodes[0];
```

For what it is worth, the PHP Manual contains [basic usage examples](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) covering how to traverse the XML structure and the specific pages for [`children()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children) and [`registerXPathNamespace()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace) show you how to work with namespaced elements with examples.

Finally, as you have seen, the output from `print_r()`/`var_dump()` with SimpleXML is not always very helpful at all!  The best way to see what you've got is to echo [`saveXML()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.savexml) which will display the XML for a given element.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm really noob at parsing XML and the examples read didn't show this kind of XML so I thought they were the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [children method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php):

```
foreach ($xml->children("soap", true) as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . ":\n";
    var_dump($v);
}
```

Comment: That's what it shows: Body: object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { }